# No puedo instalar Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, linux, composer

intento instalar laravel en mi linux en la consola, descargue el composer y todo iba bien hasta que intento instalar Laravel o cuando intento crear mi proyecto por primera vez. Me aparece esto en la consola y no importa cuantas veces lo intente o si vuelvo a instalar el composer de nuevo

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^2.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v2.1.0].
    - laravel/installer v2.1.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

Tengo linuxmint 19 y Php 7.2. lo instale con Xampp

Comment: Aquí **- laravel/installer v2.1.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.** te esta indicando que una dependencia falta en tu SO, ya probaste a instalarla?

Comment: Como puedo instalarla?

Comment: Probaste apt-get install php7.2-zip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno al fin logre solucionarlo la solucion en este caso fue

Primero instalar el php 7.3

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.3
```

Depués correr el comando

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Seguido de eso las dependencias que aparecian a medida que intentaba crear el proyecto

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Ya despues todo eso fui capaz de correr

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Y finalmente

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: Que bueno lo resolviste, no olvides cuando el sistema te lo permita marcar tu respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Sí, bien ahí que lo resolviste y compartiste la solución. Me dá curiosidad por qué cambiaste de PHP 7.2 a 7.3. Algún motivo en especial?

Comment: Cuando intente hacer `sudo apt-get install php-zip` en php 7.2 no me reconocía el comando en php 7.3 si me funciono